# C# Setting NotifySubscribers on YouTube.Videos.Insert with YouTube API v3

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube API v3 to upload videos to YouTube. I am currently able to upload a video, updating the title and description, but something very important to me is unchecking (boolean false) the NotifySubscribers property.

I have been able to find documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) and [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Videos.Insert.html), but without any implementation examples, I am feeling pretty lost.

The following is the code I currently have that is able to upload successfully, without setting NotifySubscribers to false:

```
        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("youtube_client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "test";
            video.Snippet.Description = "test description";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = @"D:\directory\YoutubeUploader\2017-02-05_02-01-32.mp4";
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I would have thought that setting that value would have been as simple as setting title, privacy status, and others were, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I've never done any real in-depth C# coding, so some of these concepts are pretty new to me.

Comment: Try changing the privacy status to public, this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/GjIoVHR3f7M;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/category$3Asafari) discussed that any video upload as private/unlisted may cause that subscribers not to be notified. Also check your YouTube channel if you have manually ticked the Notify Subscriber for every upload you have done. By default [notifySubscribers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters) is set to **True**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible with the current Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 NuGet Package (1.21.0.760). It looks like they left many methods out of the .dll, which results in very limited functionality. To get around this, I took the code from [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.cs) GitHub repository and put it in its own .cs file. I was then able to call all methods in this file. Once this was done, all I had to do to change this setting was the following:

```
videosInsertRequest.NotifySubscribers = false;
```